# How to disable scroll back to top only on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this Back To Top code on my page to get the scroll progress and to get back to top. My question is how to easily add if to this code to hide this element on mobile?

Thanks for helping out!

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    var progressPath = document.querySelector('.progress-wrap path');
    var pathLength = progressPath.getTotalLength();
    
    progressPath.style.transition = progressPath.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
    progressPath.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
    progressPath.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;
    progressPath.getBoundingClientRect();
    progressPath.style.transition = progressPath.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 10ms linear';
    
    var updateProgress = function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
      var progress = pathLength - (scroll * pathLength / height);
      progressPath.style.strokeDashoffset = progress;
    }
    updateProgress();    
    $(window).scroll(updateProgress);
    
    var offset = 50;
    var duration = 550;
    
    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
      if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.progress-wrap').addClass('active-progress');
      } else {
        jQuery('.progress-wrap').removeClass('active-progress');
      }
    });
    
    jQuery('.progress-wrap').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, duration);
      return false;
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what do you consider a mobile device? like only a phone or do you mean devices smaller than eg 400px?

Comment: The simple solution would be to leave the JS logic as it is and simply hide the `.progress-wrap` element using CSS media queries for the relevant screen sizes.

Comment: By mobile device I mean min-width: 480px. Also I tried to hide the .progress-wrap over CSS media but it didn't work. Can you more explain this way?

Answer (score 1):

You have your main desktop styles in the body of the CSS file (1024px and above) and then for specific screen sizes I'm using:

```
@media all and (min-width:960px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:801px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:569px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 568px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}
```

If you would only like the devices bigger than 568px to show the scroll button, put the css to hide the rest in the lower media queries.